# Fourier transform of cos(x)

Tags: fourier-transform

I've been stuck at an exercise that wants us to find the Fourier transform for
f(x) = cos(x).

The solution being
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sesv2.png)

Using this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAfQ5.png)

I don't know how you go from an integral of sines and cosines to a Dirac delta function, please help.

Comment: Don't you know a relation between $\cos(x)$ and $e^{ix}$ ?

Comment: Since the Dirac delta is not a function, you will either need a result already provided or you'll need some functional analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, and that the Dirac delta function is the Fourier transform of unity:

$$\delta(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dk$$

From here hopefully things will be pretty straightforward.